# How to deploy .war to heroku

Tags: java, eclipse, heroku

I have made a dynamic web project on eclipse that starts on front end with index.html . I have tested it and it works on my local apache server. I have generated the war file. Now I want to deploy the war file to heroku. I have downloaded and installed everything. I checked the internet and I came to know about creating

pom.xml , a Main class to start execution , maven assembler jar file.

As a beginner I am not able to understand how to create these files and push them to heroku. Can someone please explain me ? I dont want to create a new heroku project.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to deploy a war to Heroku:

- Using the webapp-runner (or the similar jetty-runner)
- Using the toolbelt deploy:war command

The preferred approach is using webapp-runner because it allows for more configuration of the container. Here is an [article on using webapp-runner](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner). The webapp-runner is a simple Tomcat container used to run your war file. In general, you add webapp-runner to your `pom.xml`, set your `Procfile` accordingly, and deploy to Heroku with `git push`.

The `deploy:war` approach is described in [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment). It's somewhat outdated, and does not give you much in the way of configuration.

Comment: Thank You for the answer , but I am stuck at the step at
Define value for the property group Id:
Define value for the property artifact id:
What are those? Can you please explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Export war from eclipse.
2. Login through your Heroku CLI.
3. use this command to install heroku plugin 
   `heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy`
4. Deploy with this command 
   `heroku war:deploy <path_to_war_file--app <app_name>`

For more information please visit:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment

Answer (score 0):

I used successfully:

1. heroku buildpacks:set heroku/java
2. heroku buildpacks:clear
3. heroku war:deploy target/routeplanner.war
4. heroku logs --tail

I added to Procfile

```
buildpacks:clear
war:deploy target/routeplanner.war
```

and after

```
git push
```

Build and deploy completed. In log:

```
app[api]: Deploy a68256e8
app[api]: Build succeeded
```

But create the project URL returns Error: "in the application and your page could not be served"

In log: 
`heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running"`

But why do I have to request these commands again from console to reanimate application work?

1. heroku buildpacks:clear
2. heroku war:deploy target/routeplanner.war