# How to deploy java application to heroku

Tags: java, heroku, salesforce, heroku-toolbelt

Does anyone know how to deploy java application (from eclipse) to heroku ?
There is no documentation over the internet.

Is it ok to deploy 'java web application' ? does it have to be a maven project ?
I don't understand ...
Are there specific files that should be in the project ? (Procfile, .gitignore)

I am sitting on that for 2 days now and I'm so frustrated.
Any information, links to useful websites will be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155657/how-to-deploy-war-to-heroku

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923486/steps-needed-to-deploy-war-on-heroku

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment

Answer (score 1):

You should read [Deploying Java Applications to Heroku from Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-to-heroku-from-eclipse-or-intellij-idea)

Or watch [How to Deploy to Heroku from Eclipse](http://jkutner.github.io/2015/02/23/heroku-eclipse-demo.html)

Or read [Heroku War Deployment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment)